# more effective way to join characters into a single string in PHP

Tags: php, string, iteration, concatenation

i am iterating, character by character, through a lengthy string and do specific operations on its substrings.

at one point i have to merge smaller strings with the larger one, here i am unsure which is more effective:

- simply add up character by character through iteration like

  ```
  for(some iteration){
    large_string.=some_character;
  }
  ```
- or first add these single characters into a smaller temporary string and then concatenate it with a single operation

  ```
  for(some iteration){
    temporary_string.=some_character;
  }
  large_string.=temporary_string;
  ```

Comment: i was asking because some language could concatenate the string in a way that it would have to go through all the string in order to append something. that way, the second solution would be of course more appropriate. however, by the answer i guess php doesn't take the previous string into account when concatenating a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approach will take same amount of time to create new string. There is no time difference.

Comment: or you can `implode("",$iteration)` to get your string back

Answer (score 1):

Both the iterations are same thus will take the same time and the same amount of resources.

But if Your input array has this structure:

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
```

You should not be using Your own iteration and string contatenation but use `implode` this way:

```
$large_string .= implode('', $array);
```

as **this is much quicker**. And even if the input array is not of that structure it should be quicker to use this snippet (didn't test it):

```
$tmp = array();
foreach($somethings as $something) { // <-- foreach loop is quicker then for loop
    $tmp[] = $something['my_char'];
}
$large_string .= implode('', $tmp);
```

The use of **PHP native functions** is always better and quicker then implementing the same logic Yourself... At least because You usually have to type less.

Comment: thanks for the answer, can't vote two as correct :)
however, i'm really sceptic about building a whole friggin array of characters just to convert string into it and then imploding it being more effective than concating two strings...

Comment: @user1916182 I was just guessing as You didn't give us the real iteration, just `for(some iteration){` - hard to say what are you iterating over and why :-)